# In Apple OS X (10.11 El Capitan) overwrite system files

Tags: permissions, osx-el-capitan

I am trying to install Pikers Alpha 64 Bit emulator in El Capitan.

I seem to be having a heck of a time overwriting the boot.efi file within 10.11...

- I have disabled SIP.
- Though I used `chflags nouchg` to change file permissions as suggested...
- I have used `cp` with various flags to attempt to overwrite the OS X system file boot.efi with the Piker version...
- all I get is "permission denied".

Any ideas?

Comment: I think either you haven't actually disabled System Integrity Protection even though you think you did, or you're not using `sudo`.

Comment: I had to use a different computer (a 2008 3,1)...

Comment: Sorry am not real good at posting formatted txt in this thing yet... 1)I had to use a different computer (a 2008 3,1) to accomplish that task... 2) had to boot of another drive (used 10.10.? to boot) 3) changed lots of system parameters on that drive un-hid system files and such and may have disabled SIP but I don't remember 4) mounted the second drive (created a directory and then mounted the drive there) 5) changed to the directory and copied over the file 6) mounted the "recovery disk" and changed the boot.efi there also -catch part 2

Comment: PART2 -- (or each time it reboots it "fixes" the boot.efi back to the original not the Pikers Alpha... 

Then ran and installed the script that keeps that in place or each update will overwrite the Pikers boot.efi file (sorry for the life of me can't remember name - but it is easy to find) - did updates from 10.11.4 to 10.11.5 (&6) and all stayed in place! Good luck